# Volume Encryption plus FileVault -- redundant?

Tags: disk-utility, filevault

My startup disk was formatted as "Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)". Then I installed macOS Sierra, and it prompted me to turn on FileVault. I did, not remembering that the disk was already encrypted, and it went through the slow process of encrypting the data.

Is my disk double-encrypted now? I assumed it wouldn't have asked me to turn on FileVault if it was already encrypted. Should I turn FileVault off again?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think it's double-encrypted. I suspect you created a 'Disk Password' when encrypting in Disk Utility and then you added users to unlock the disk when enabling FileVault. Out of curiosity, what do the following show?

```
diskutil cs list
sudo fdesetup list -e
```

*Answers from original poster*:

`diskutil cs list` shows:

```
+-- Logical Volume Group B48571B2-985A-48B3-91F0-0C9AA9FFBE0A
|   =========================================================
|   Name:         Macintosh HD
|   Status:       Online
|   Size:         511250432000 B (511.3 GB)
|   Free Space:   36864 B (36.9 KB)
|   |
|   +-< Physical Volume C60946EB-D0F1-4A80-BAAF-6D7F0B716C2A
|   |   ----------------------------------------------------
|   |   Index:    0
|   |   Disk:     disk0s2
|   |   Status:   Online
|   |   Size:     511250432000 B (511.3 GB)
|   |
|   +-> Logical Volume Family 3C90D9A1-05C4-4D94-B20F-05F469418176
|       ----------------------------------------------------------
|       Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
|       Encryption Status:       Unlocked
|       Conversion Status:       Complete
|       High Level Queries:      Fully Secure
|       |                        Passphrase Required
|       |                        Accepts New Users
|       |                        Has Visible Users
|       |                        Has Volume Key
|       |
|       +-> Logical Volume 38FE20AC-17E6-4C37-B465-FB270BE91718
|           ---------------------------------------------------
|           Disk:                  disk2
|           Status:                Online
|           Size (Total):          510883004416 B (510.9 GB)
|           Conversion Progress:   Complete
|           Revertible:            Yes (unlock and decryption required)
|           LV Name:               Macintosh HD
|           Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
|           Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

`sudo fdesetup list -e` shows:

```
ESCROW  UUID                                                                     TYPE USER
        799FBB35-D5A3-443E-B397-E934AECC6D51                                  OS User myusername
        1B4714C8-EB0E-42D4-A2D4-F45E19CA6890                              iCloud User
```

Comment: That looks very similar to my output. There's nothing unexpected in the CoreStorage list from diskutil. I still don't think there's double encryption. What happens when you boot up, do you have have to enter a password twice?

Comment: Nope, just once, early in the startup sequence. So it's acting the same way it has ever since I formatted the disk as encrypted.